# mutex для распределённого приложения

Tags: php, redis, mutex

Приложение берёт из БД пачку id объектов и проделывает с ними некие вычисления, занимающие до нескольких минут. Сами объекты – набор файлов на диске.

Пора расширяться на несколько серверов. Нужно, чтобы случайно не совпало, и один объект не попал в работу одновременно на нескольких машинах – это приведёт к сбою.

Ещё будут процессы бэкапа, garbage collection / стирания устаревших данных и другие типы работ с объектами, которые так же должны «уважать» эксклюзивную залоченность объекта.

Стек: Linux, PHP, MySQL, Redis.

Пробую просто помещать в set в Redis id объектов, взятых в обработку. Но есть неотловленный пока косяк: иногда эти id зависают в Redis. Видимо, бывает аварийное завершение, при котором не удаляется из набора обработанный id.

Можно завести таблицу в БД, куда заносить id в работе. Менее привлекательно, т.к. задействует диск, в отличие от чисто-памяти Redis.

Как лучше организовать mutex (mutual exclusion, взаимное исключение), «запирание» объектов, которые попадают в работу? Разумно ли использовать свою реализацию, или есть лёгкие/надёжные общепринятые?

**Upd.** нашёл предложение решения [распределённого mutex на Redis](http://redis.io/topics/distlock).

Comment: Не смотрели в сторону очередей? Разбиваете задачу на пачки размером в N-объектов (где N может быть и 1), на нескольких серверах запускаете консьюмеров и всё.

Comment: @zhukov-roman поднять Gearman и через него пускать задания думал. Тут ещё вот какая особенность: ещё будут накладываться процессы бэкапа и garbage collection / стирания устаревших данных и другие, которые так же должны «уважать» эксклюзивную залоченность объекта. Так что нужен именно mutex.

Comment: А чем не устроили [транзакционные блокировки в самом MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)?

Comment: надежные, общепринятые - imho для серьезной работы надо использовать серьезные СУБД, которые поддерживают блокировки записи на уровне строки и при этом возможности неблокирующего приложение селекта.

Comment: @D-side тем, что запираемые объекты не в БД, а в файловой системе живут.

Comment: ...так у вас **одна файловая система**, в которую смотрят **несколько баз данных**?

Comment: Нет, одна FS (в дальнейшем разшардится), одна БД. Удалённые воркеры подключаются к FS по NFS, и к MySQL через TCP. Но это к делу мало относится: мне нужен надёжный mutex.

Comment: Так раз одна база, её можно использовать для блокировок, нет? Кстати, пока я тут, рекомендую читнуть про advisory locks в PostgreSQL. Может, какие новые идеи возникнут.